# Visual Studio Code C# "Run Without Debugging" error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I have Visual Studio Code 1.56.2 installed on Ubuntu 18.04 to develop Python.

A few days ago I have installed ".NET Core for C# coding on Linux" so I can code C# with Visual Studio Code.

When I try to run the "Program.cs" (hello world) app I get a pop up window with error "You don't have an extension for debugging C#. Should we find a C# extension in the Marketplace?"

I already have installed "C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp). Microsoft" as shown here:

[image]

Here is my workspace structure:

[image]

I would appreciate any help in resolving this.

Comment: Can you try to close and open VSCODE again?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues I just tried closing and opening VSCODE. I am getting the same error, here is the screenshot: http://fortitudevolution.com/VisualStudioCode/images/Selection_999(3041).png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have both `launch.json` and `task.json` in a folder named `.vscode`, in your project/solution root directory.

If you don-t, you can go to the menu `Run` > `Add Configuration...`

[image]

It should create the files automatically, but if you can't, here is a sample of what is the content of those files (you'd need to adjust to your local fylesistem/project/version values)

tasks.json:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "shell",
            "args": [
                "build",
                // Ask dotnet build to generate full paths for file names.
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                // Do not generate summary otherwise it leads to duplicate errors in Problems panel
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "silent"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net5.0/net.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "stopAtEntry": false
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. The  I had to manually create a launch.json file as you have shown to get pass this error. Now I am getting this error: "Couldn''t find a debug adapter descriptor for debug type 'coreclr' (extension might have failed to activate)". Here is te screen shot http://fortitudevolution.com/VisualStudioCode/images/Selection_999(3042).png

Comment: I just uninstalled and reinstalled the C# extension as recommended in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58257448/dotnet-core-3-0-compilation-issues-in-vscode Now I am getting this error "launch program'~/MyApp/bin/Debug/net5.0/net.dll' does not exist.

Comment: I just got this to work! had to change the launch.json "program" line to point to MyApp.dll, like this **"program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net5.0/MyApp.dll",** Thank you @Rodriguo for your help!