# Error on installing fortran-language-server (MacOS)

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, fortran, gfortran

I am new to MacOS and I am having issues running Fortran code in VSCode. I followed all steps from this: (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oukqHpJkdok&list=PL92_6M30qOELuwqSpd5-LkxyVD-Lluxoe&index=4), including the installation of homebrewer and gfortran. However, when I run on my terminal "sudo pip3 install fortran-language-server", which should enable the command "fortls", it runs but the command doesn't work and gives an error message.

The error message is:

```
Unexpected error: Line endings must be \r\n
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pedro/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fortls/langserver.py", line 115, in run
    request = self.conn.read_message()
  File "/Users/pedro/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fortls/jsonrpc.py", line 110, in read_message
    return self._receive()
  File "/Users/pedro/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fortls/jsonrpc.py", line 95, in _receive
    length = self._read_header_content_length(line)
  File "/Users/pedro/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fortls/jsonrpc.py", line 81, in _read_header_content_length
    raise JSONRPC2ProtocolError("Line endings must be \\r\\n")
fortls.jsonrpc.JSONRPC2ProtocolError: Line endings must be \r\n
```

Back in the VSCode, when I try to run a simple code in fortran it gives me a message saying: "gfortran can't found on path, update your settings with a proper path or disable the linter."

Could this error be cause by lack of support to the new processer (ARM)?

Also, is there other ways to setup fortran for VSCode?

Comment: Do you have gfortran in your path? What do you get if you execute `which gfortran` in your command line?

Comment: yes, it's on `opt/homebrew/bin/gfortran`

Comment: I just checked and I can compile the code, but only by clicking on the button of from Code Run. Also it runs only on the terminal and I can't debug.

Comment: Do you have a `tasks.json` and a `launch.json` in a folder named `.vscode` in your project root? Take a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67678278/visual-studio-code-c-sharp-run-without-debugging-error/67680772#67680772).

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, I don't think I even have a .vscode folder. Sorry for not knowing such basic things. As I said, this is my first macbook. Where should this folder be? In my Users's folder? Also, what contents should be in the .json files? Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

There were two issues. First I had not installed Xcode properly. Secondly, pip3 was installing in the anaconda directory.

After reinstalling Xcode I used this line I solved the problem:

`/opt/homebrew/bin/pip3 install fortran-language-server`